# Use autocd and CDPATH together in a bash?

Tags: bash, cd-command

In a bash, is there a way to combine `autocd` and `CDPATH`, that is, to go to a subdirectory of a `CDPATH` element without typing `cd` before the dir name?

For example, if i have these directories:

- ~
- ~/Leute
- ~/Leute/Hinz
- ~/Leute/Kunz
- ~/Dinge
- ~/Dinge/Haus
- ~/Dinge/Auto

and do

```
~$ shopt -s autocd
~$ export CDPATH=":~/Leute:~/Dinge"
```

then i can do

```
~$ Leute
```

and end up in the ~/Leute directory (that is the `autocd` thing)

```
~/Leute$
```

and i can do

```
~/Leute$ cd Auto
```

and end up in ~/Dinge/Auto (the `CDPATH` thing)

```
~/Dinge/Auto$
```

but combining the two seems not to work.
For example starting in ~/Leute i can’t jump to ~/Dinge/Auto without an explicit `cd`:

```
~/Leute$ Auto
bash: Auto: Command not found...
```

Is there a reason for this? Or is there something else needed to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Whether by design or oversight, it seems that the test for whether you've typed a directory name doesn't search the `CDPATH` variable:

`execute.cmd.c`, function `execute_simple_command`:

```c
  if (autocd && interactive && words->word && is_dirname (words->word->word))
    {
      words = make_word_list (make_word ("cd"), words);
      xtrace_print_word_list (words, 0);
      goto run_builtin;
    }
```

The definition of `is_dirname` is in the same source file:

```c
/* Return 1 if the file found by searching $PATH for PATHNAME, defaulting
   to PATHNAME, is a directory.  Used by the autocd code below. */
static int
is_dirname (pathname)
     char *pathname;
{
  char *temp;
  int ret;

  temp = search_for_command (pathname, 0);
  ret = (temp ? file_isdir (temp) : file_isdir (pathname));
  free (temp);
  return ret;
}
```

From this, it appears that `autocd` will find directories on `PATH`, but I tested it with `X11` (for `/usr/bin/X11/`) and got the error `X11: No such file or directory`.